# The Best Way For Two Sequential SELECT Table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have two tables to send consecutive queries.

For example, table A yields 1,2,3 ..
Then, look for data in table B of query 1,2,3 ..

**tableA**

```
_____________________
|   uid |   rate    |
|   1   |   1       |
|   1   |   2       |
|   1   |   3       |
|   2   |   4       |
```

**tableB**

```
_________________________
|   rate    |   text    |
|   1       |   ONE     |
|   2       |   TWO     |
|   3       |   THREE   |
|   4       |   FOUR    |
```

===

```
<?php
    $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE uid=1");
    $user = $sql->fetch_array();
    $ratings = $user['rate']; //1,2,3

    $sql2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE rate IN('".$ratings."')");
    $text = $sql2->fetch_array();
    $results = $text['text']; //ONE, TWO, THREE
?>
```

How best to do that?

Comment: The best way is join two table with rate fields

Comment: How to apply that way

Comment: Read a SQL tutorial that explains joins. It's basic to SQL programming.

Comment: `fetch_array()` only returns 1 row, how are you getting `1,2,3` in `$ratings`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
Select tableA.*,tableB.* 
from tableA 
join tableB on tableA.rate=tableB.rate 
where tableA.uid=1
```

Comment: I've tried it. But when making ECHO, nothing shows up there. Is there something wrong?

Comment: im test `echo $results['text'];` no results